# Grabbing Lists of Members of Google+ Communities

Tags: python, api, google-plus

The [Google+ Communities](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/communities/) service appears to have launched without an API. Has anyone managed to come up with a Python script that can pull down a list of members of a Google+ Community?

The calling URL to view community members is of the form:

```
https://plus.google.com/u/0/_/communities/members?hl=en_GB&ozv=es_oz_20121205.15_p1&avw=sq%3A1&_reqid=2638839&rt=j
```

and then for following pages:

```
https://plus.google.com/u/0/_/communities/readmembers?hl=en_GB&ozv=es_oz_20121205.15_p1&avw=sq%3A4&_reqid=3038839&rt=j
https://plus.google.com/u/0/_/communities/readmembers?hl=en_GB&ozv=es_oz_20121205.15_p1&avw=sq%3A4&_reqid=3238839&rt=j
https://plus.google.com/u/0/_/communities/readmembers?hl=en_GB&ozv=es_oz_20121205.15_p1&avw=sq%3A4&_reqid=3438839&rt=j
```

I'm not sure if the `_reqid` count is actually doing the paging?

The data returned bears at least a passing resemblance to data used by Google+ friends lists, I think, so ideally what I'm looking for is a Python Library that provides a fake Google+ social API that can grab:
1) Google+ friends lists, and
2) lists of members of Google+ communities.

Comment: I tried to make POST request with curl, and i got data:  

    $ curl "https://plus.google.com/u/0/_/communities/members" -d "f.req=%5B%22109254488709825102030%22%2Cnull%5D&"  Maybe this help you.